# How to escape Indian currency symbol "₹" (&#8377) in Java?

Tags: java, html

I tried this :

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4;

String output = escapeHtml4("Price for extra guest/child above 12 years is ₹ ​599");
```

And it returns me the same string and does not encodes the ₹ symbol to &#8377

Comment: try `output.replaceAll("₹", "&#8377")`

Comment: 8377 is the **ASCII** value of the **INDIAN RUPEE SIGN** as mentioned at http://utf8icons.com . Your program returns the ASCII value instead of the **₹** character because the **₹** sign is not supported by the platform. At the most you can try printing `(char)8377` but that would show a box instead of the character, thus indicating its non compatibility.

Comment: Why do you want to escape it in the first place? Why not use UTF8 to encode your HTML document, and use the symbol directly, rather than an HTML entity?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry. I am a newbie in this. Let me explain the actual scene.
I hit an internal API which returns me a JSON something similar to this:

{
      addOn: {
            "0" : "Price for extra guest/child above 12 years is ₹ ​599"
      } 
}

I need to parse the JSON. Extract the addons, wrap it in HTML and send it across. I wrap it in HTML as:

"<ul><li>"+addOn.toString()+"</li><ul>"

But when I test this HTML in browser, it displays a group on unfamiliar characters in place of currency sign. I am not sure what the issue is. And I am not sure if "escape" is right word that I used.

Comment: Well, the HTML is probably not using a character encoding able to encode that character. UTF8 is able to encode every possible Unicode character. Post a minimal complete example reproducing the problem, so that we can help.